# error empty cluster in k-means

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-mining, k-means

Hello
I have clustered data.my code similar kmeans in matlab.but in function gcentroids
has error in 'if any(members)' . in fact one of the clusters is empty and Returns the value NaN .

Comment: Try providing some code for us, or a screenshot or datasets

Comment: pleas give me youe email

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the initial centroids, k-means can indeed produce empty clusters.

Try again with a different set of initial clusters!

Comment: I must clustering with a certain number of k.

Comment: Retry with a new random seed.